# is it working properly with share pointers (c++)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a code such as this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<int> BUFFER_TYPE  
class MyClass
{
     BUFFER_TYPE buffer;
 public:
     MyClass(int n)
     {
         buffer=std::make_shared<int> (n);
     }
     MyClass()
     {
         buffer=null;
     }
     BUFFER_TYPE GetBuffer()
     {
          return buffer;
     } 
}

MyClass GetMyClass()
{
    MyClass x(200);
    return x;
}

void SetMyClass(MyClass cl)
{
    MyClass y=cl;
    BUFFER_TYPE buffer=y.GetBuffer();
    buffer[20]=100;
}

void main()
{
    MyClass c(100);
    MyClass d=c;
    MyClass e=GetMyClass();
    SetMyClass(e);
    BUFFER_TYPE buffer=e.GetBuffer();
    printf("Buffer is %d\n",buffer[20]);
}
```

Is there any memory leak with this code?

Is it working properly?

Am I using shared_ptr correctly?

Please note that buffer should be a pointer to an array of say 100 int and not one integer.

Comment: I dont' think you should hide your `shared_ptr` behind a macro. At least use a `typedef`

Comment: @arne: Updates the code. Please check it.

Comment: In this case instead of macro/typedef you could use template class to specify what kind of data you want to store in buffer (if I'm correct your intent behind making this macro was to have an easy way of changing stored type).

Comment: @Dino The aim is to type simpler and be able to change the type at any time.

Comment: Adding to arne's remark, if you have typedefs that are mainly used for the implementaion of a class, you might want to move them into the class, in this case into the class' public section. This says more explicitly: BUFFER_TYPE is mainly used by MyClass and is generally used in the context of MyCLass. Otherwise, BUFFER_TYPE is simply a name that has no obvious relationship to anything.

Since MyClass's public interface exposes BUFFER_TYPE it needs to be public, otherwise you can move the typedef to the class' private section.

Answer (score 3):

Since `buffer` is supposed to be an array of `int`, the code is not correct. `std::shared_ptr` manages a pointer to a **single** object. Instead of `std::shared_ptr<int>` use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: If I use a vector, does it work properly? No memory leak? no loss of data when creating object inside a function? Can I saev and read it from a file like an allocated buffer?

Comment: @mans As long as you don't explicitly allocate memory on the heap (aka `new`) you cannot run into memory leaks when using `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't use a macro. Just spell out the type or use a `typedef`.

Secondly, no, you are not allocating an array. You are allocating a single `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated already you're allocating memory for single int, not an array. You could try with shared_array (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm), or

```
shared_ptr<vector<int> >
```

if what you really want is to share this buffer.

Comment: You cannot just use `shared_ptr<int>` to store `int[]`; if you absolutely need to do this, use `shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[N], std::default_delete<int[]>());`

Comment: Yeah, that's true, don't know why the part "<vector<int>" was not showing until I made this into 'code block'. I didn't notice this, thanks.